# FVM Flutter configuration

Tags: flutter, dart, fvm

I installed FVM, but it only works in CMD/Power Shell and only when i run it as an `Administrator`
If I try to do a command as an admin, the CMD shuts down. On an another note, the Power Shell gives me the code line

```
"Error: Unable to find git in your PATH"
```

when i try to do a command in it. The same thing happens when i try to use dart commands too.

Can someone help me?

[image]

I expected using flutter commands in the terminal without run as admin.

Answer (score 0):

the solution I found was in the Visual Studio Code settings JSON file. You need to remove the existing configuration and add a new one to make it work with FVM.
Remove the following configuration:
json

```
{
  "dart.flutterSdkPath": ".fvm/flutter_sdk",
  "search.exclude": {
    "**/.fvm": true
  },
  "files.watcherExclude": {
    "**/.fvm": true
  }
}
```

And add the following configuration to make it work with all the versions you have downloaded with FVM:
json

```
{
  "dart.flutterSdkPaths": ["/Users/usr/fvm/versions"]
}
```

Make sure to replace "/Users/usr/fvm/versions" with the actual path to the "versions" folder where FVM stores the downloaded Flutter versions on your system.
This configuration change will allow Visual Studio Code to recognize and use the Flutter versions managed by FVM.
You can find more information about this configuration on the FVM website at

https://fvm.app/docs/getting_started/configuration/.
I hope this helps!